# How to get data from xml using Xpath

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xpath-2.0

I have an xml field like below

`<c_text> <b> 1 <b> ".Some text" </c_te`xt>

I want result like

```
"1. Some text"
```

how to use xpath for this

I used `/c_text/text()` but im getting partial result ie ".Some text"
data inside  tag is missing.
any way to solve this ?

Comment: Include at least part of the xml that has that field in your question to get better help

Answer (score 0):

`/c_text/text()` selects the text node children of `c_text`.  Instead of `text()`, you should leverage the concept of a nodes [***string-value***](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#dt-string-value)...

For this XML, corrected to be well-formed and eliminated of the likely mistaken use of string quotation,

```
<c_text><b>1</b>. Some text</c_text>
```

This XPath,

```
string(/c_text)
```

will select the string-value of `c_text`,

```
 1. Some text
```

as requested.

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this:

```
<xsl:template match="c_text">
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```